# How do I let a user input data and create an object with input dialog?

Tags: java

These are my requirements:

> 1. Write a program (Person) that has the following attributes: name, adress, age.
> 2. Write four constructors
> 3. Write get set methods
> 4. Write a toString method.
> 5. Write a seperate program (TestClass) and let the user enter the name, adress and age in three different dialogboxes and then create an object of the class Person and store the data in this object.
> 6. In the same way, let the user create four more objects but use one of the constructors with each object.
> 7. View the data for each object through a dialog box, using the toString method.

That was my instructions and below is my code for the program(class) Person:

```
public class Person
{
   private String name;
   private String adress;
   public int age;

public Person(String name, String adress, int age)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.adress=adress;
    this.age=age;
}
public Person(String name, int age)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.adress="";
}
public Person(String name, String adress)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.adress=adress;
    this.age=0;
}
public Person(String name)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.adress="";
    this.age=0;
}
public Person()
{
    this.name="";
    this.adress="";
    this.age=0;
}
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name=name;
}
public void setAdress(String adress)
{
    this.adress=adress;
}
public void setAge(int age)
{
    this.age=age;
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public int getAge()
{
    return age;
}
public String getAdress()
{
    return adress;
}
public String toString()
{
      return " Name : " + name + " Age: " + age+ " " + " Adress: " + adress;
}
}
```

And hereeee is the code for my program TestClass. Look at the comments

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
     

// 5. Write a seperate program (TestClass) and let the user enter the name, adress and age
        int r1; 
        String name=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Whats your name ?");  
        String adress=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Whats your adress? "); 
        String sR1=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your age? ");  
        r1=Integer.parseInt(sR1); 
  
        Person p1=new Forening(name, adress, r1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p1.toString());
        
// 6.let the user create four more objects but use one of the constructors with each object.
 
        Person p3=new Person("Johanna", 2004);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p3.toString());
        
        Forening p4=new Person("John", "JavaScriptstreet 1");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p4.toString());
        
        Person p5=new Person("Sandra");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p5.toString());
```

Obviously I'm not doing soooomething right!! It's the part where I'm supposed to let the user input data through dialog boxes and let the user create objects of the class to store the data and then show the data that I'm struggling with..

Comment: If you're stuck at trying to create a dialog for the user to input data, almost all of this code is unnecessary. Just focus on working out that one part; worry about the `Person` class and passing values into the constructor for that after.

Comment: Requirement #6 is just the same as #5 with slight tweaks, so you should do the same thing again, but ask for slightly different input.